# why 10.4.14- mariaDb couldn't save chinese word?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I had installed xampp 7.4 version. And it had 10.4.14- mariaDb   for
database. I had set all the charset=utf8 .
the status in mysql is all fine in utf8. But when I set a database table for:
create table db1(name varchar(10)) charset = utf8;
And all this is well now when I save a record:
set names uft8;insert into db1("數學");
Save was successful, but the display was wrong when i command:
select name from db1;
It couldn't show chinese word :

'? ?'

I have serach for the font for zh-tw in mysql dir and couldn't
find it. Anyone else to teach me how to resolved this question?
Thanks.

Comment: you need utf8mb4, not utf8

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I use uft8mb4 successfully. But still got        '? ?'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

Add more Detailed  I'd done   :
[image]

Comment: my status  since right But still I could'n got display chinese in

Answer (score 0):

Finally , that I foud that's because of the win 7 .
I use win 7. And the xampp didn't support the win 7
chinese . Alothough I know that micorsoft didn't support   win7 anymore , but I still wana to figure out where to
corecct this bug.
Now that I use the win 10 system. And It work fine with mysql chinese version. Thanks for the trouble.